# Error from Word Extractor

Tags: java, linux, amazon-web-services, liferay, apache-poi

I am extracting text from various document files like *doc*, *docx* etc. using *apache poi*. My code is running well in *Windows*, but after deploying to test server it's not working.

Server OS: Amazon Linux
Env.: AWS

Here is my code snippet:

```
                if(extension.equals("docx")){
                    XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(resume));
                    XWPFWordExtractor we = new XWPFWordExtractor(document);
                    resumeAsText = we.getText();
                } else if(extension.equals("doc")){

                    Word6Extractor extractor = new Word6Extractor(new FileInputStream(resume));
                    resumeAsText = extractor.getText();
                } else if(extension.equals("pdf")){
                    PDFParser parser = new PDFParser(new FileInputStream(resume));
                    parser.parse();
                    COSDocument cosDoc = parser.getDocument();
                    PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
                    PDDocument pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc);
                    resumeAsText = pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc);
                    cosDoc.close();
                    pdDoc.close();
                } else if(extension.equals("rtf")){
                    RTFEditorKit rtfParser = new RTFEditorKit();
                    Document document = rtfParser.createDefaultDocument();
                    rtfParser.read(new FileInputStream(resume), document, 0);
                    resumeAsText = document.getText(0, document.getLength());                       
                }
```

I am getting this error:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(Appli
11:18:34,337 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-85][PortletServlet:116] javax.portlet.PortletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils.toByteArray(Ljava/io/InputStream;)[B
javax.portlet.PortletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils.toByteArray(Ljava/io/InputStream;)[B
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayPortlet.callActionMethod(LiferayPortlet.java:166)
    at com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.callActionMethod(MVCPortlet.java:247)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayPortlet.processAction(LiferayPortlet.java:78)
    at com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.processAction(MVCPortlet.java:210)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:71)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:48)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:112)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at cationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:605)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:544)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:604)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeAction(InvokerPortletImpl.java:649)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.processAction(InvokerPortletImpl.java:312)
```

Comment: Looks like you have an old copy of Apache POI on your classpath - did you try following the [Apache POI FAQ for this](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006)?

Comment: @Gagravarr : Thanks for your reply. I am using poi 3.11.

**Here is the list of jars I am using**
commons-codec-1.9.jar
commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
poi-3.11-20141221.jar
poi-ooxml-3.11-20141221.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.11-20141221.jar
poi-scratchpad-3.11-20141221.jar
xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar.

Comment: As the error message and the FAQ both make clear, the problem is that your JVM has a different idea about what jars you are using... You need to find the older POI jar on your classpath, and remove that. You may not think you're using different POI jars, but the JVM silently disagrees...